# Equivalence between Hasse bound and Weil conjecture for elliptic curves

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $q = p^{n}$ and let $E$ be an elliptic curve. Hasse's bound  tell us that
$$
|\sharp E(\mathbb{F}_{q}) - q - 1| \leq 2\sqrt{q}
$$
for any $q$. We can prove this without using Weil conjecture for elliptic curves.

But I heard that Hasse's bound is equivalent to Weil conjecture for elliptic curves.
I know weil conjecutre deduces this inequality, but how this conjecture deduce Weil conjecture for elliptic curves?

Any reference is also appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think that statement might be imprecise: my understanding is that the Hasse bound is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis for elliptic curves, which was the last part of the Weil conjecture's to be proven. Specifically, the Riemann hypothesis states that the two roots of the Frobenius polynomial $1- a_qX +qT^2$ factors as $(1-\alpha T)(1-\beta T)$ with $|\alpha| = |\beta| = |q|^{1 / 2}$. Hasse's bound exactly tells you that $a_q^2 - 4q \le 0$ -- i.e. the polynomial has two complex roots or a repeated root, which is equivalent to the norm statement.

Comment: Weil conjecture for elliptic curves includes α and β is not two real numbers?https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures. ←For example, here, in Riemann hypothesis, I cannot find such description.

Comment: I haven't said that they can't be real: in principal, they could both be $\pm \sqrt q$!

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was awkward. In other words, from which condition of Weil conjecture, you deduce $a^2-4q≦0$?

Comment: This is very specific to the elliptic curves case. The Riemann hypothesis states that the two $1- aT + qT^2$ factors as $(1-\alpha T)(1-\beta T)$ with $|\alpha| = |\beta| = q^{1 / 2}$. Since $a = \alpha + \beta$ by definition, by the triangle inequality, it's clear that $|a| \le |\alpha| + |\beta| = 2\sqrt q$. Putting both directions together, you see that the Hasse principal is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis (but not to the other parts of the Weil conjectures)

Comment: α and β are complex conjugate seems to me trivial  because $1-aT＋qT^2$ is quadratic equation over real number, so two roots are always conjugate. But some book （for example, Silverman's the arithmetic of elliptic curves'） proves this fact with nontrivial way... What am I missing?

Comment: It's not true that the roots of a quadratic equation in $\mathbb R[x]$ are complex conjugate. It's only true if the roots are complex.

Comment: Roots are in $C$ is assumed condition. What kind of counterexample are there?

Comment: I meant if the roots are not real. A priori, there's no reason we can't have $\alpha = 1, \beta = q$.